# Not displaying nunit tests in visual studion after NUnit integration in Visual Studio

Tags: tfs2010, visualstudio, nunit

I have downloaded the vISUAL Nunit 2010 and also edited the .vbproj file guid. But still Visual Studio is not displaying nunit tests. Any idea what I am missing here.

Comment: Stupid "is it plugged in question" from me, but, are you selecting the appropriate namespace/class in the gui?

Comment: yes, even after selection It is not showing any thing in test View

Answer (score 3):

it might help someone. As My mistake assuming that visual Nunit will show the test in test View but it will show tests by selecting  View-> otherwindows-> Visual Nunit. Then It will display all your tests. Also If you want to see all you nunit tests in test View just like mstest then you have to install nunit for VS.

Comment: Good job on figuring it out!